# How to categorize numerical ranges in r

Tags: r, categories

I have a data frame, where each column corresponds to patientID and each row corresponds to a particular gene value.

```
df <- data.frame(Hugo_Symbol=c("CDKN2A", "JUN", "IRS2","MTOR",
                           "NRAS"),
                  A183=c(-0.19,NA,2.01,0.4,1.23),
                  A185=c(0.11,2.45,NA,NA,1.67),
                  A186=c(1.19,NA,2.41,0.78,1.93),
                  A187=c(2.78,NA,NA,0.7,2.23),
                  A188=c(NA,NA,NA,2.4,1.23))
head(df)

  Hugo_Symbol  A183 A185 A186 A187 A188
1      CDKN2A -0.19 0.11 1.19 2.78   NA
2         JUN    NA 2.45   NA   NA   NA
3        IRS2  2.01   NA 2.41   NA   NA
4        MTOR  0.40   NA 0.78 0.70 2.40
5        NRAS  1.23 1.67 1.93 2.23 1.23
```

I would like to assign the following categories for each value:

- if the value in the range (-Inf, -2) assign category "1"
- if the value in the range (-2, 2) assign category "2"
- if the value in the range (2,Inf) assign category "3"
- if the value is NA assign category "0"

I tried to use a `cut` function to do that. My code looks like that:

```
df2<- df[cut(df,
             breaks=c(-Inf,-2,2,Inf),
             labels=c("1","2","3"))]
```

However, I received the following error:

> Error in cut.default(df, breaks = c(-Inf, -2, 2, Inf), labels = c("1",  :
> 'x' must be numeric

I believe it's because I have NA values in my table. I don't know how to assign the category "0" for NA values. The desired output should look like that:

```
Hugo_Symbol A183 A185 A186 A187 A188
1      CDKN2A    2    2    2    1    0
2         JUN    0    1    0    0    0
3        IRS2    1    0    1    0    0
4        MTOR    2    0    2    2    1
5        NRAS    2    2    2    1    2
```

How I can fix this error and replace each value with predefined category I have mentioned above?

Thank you for your help!

Olha

Comment: Please include a sample of your data in the text of your question, rather than as a link. A good way to do this would be to include the output of running `dput(df[1:5,1:5])` so that we have a tiny 5x5 sample of data to work with.

Comment: `df` is the entire data.frame. Does it have only one column or something? Otherwise you need to sepecify the column you want to transform. And i'm not sure when you are using the `[]` to index here. It's important to distinguish between transforming the data.frame itself and a column in the data.frame. But `cut()` is the right function to use here.

Comment: I want to transform the data.frame itself. I have added a toy example for my table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `findInterval` in `base R`

```
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], findInterval, c(-Inf, -2, 2, Inf))
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you have is correct but you need to apply it for each column. You can do it via `lapply` in base R :

```
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], cut, c(-Inf,-2,2,Inf), c("1","2","3"))
df

#  Hugo_Symbol A183 A185 A186 A187 A188
#1      CDKN2A    2    2    2    3 <NA>
#2         JUN <NA>    3 <NA> <NA> <NA>
#3        IRS2    3 <NA>    3 <NA> <NA>
#4        MTOR    2 <NA>    2    2    3
#5        NRAS    2    2    2    3    2
```

Or use `across` in `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(across(starts_with('A'), cut, c(-Inf,-2,2,Inf),c("1","2","3")))
```