# R - Numerical variables not transforming to class

Tags: r, type-conversion, transformation

I have a variable containing a numerical double variable from around 0 up until 200. I try to convert the variable to classes by means of the following code:

```
# Convert numerical values to classes
Dataset$Klant_Test_Resultaat_Links[Dataset$Klant_Test_Resultaat_Links <= 20] <- "1"
Dataset$Klant_Test_Resultaat_Links[Dataset$Klant_Test_Resultaat_Links > 20 & Dataset$Klant_Test_Resultaat_Links <= 35] <- "2"
Dataset$Klant_Test_Resultaat_Links[Dataset$Klant_Test_Resultaat_Links > 35 & Dataset$Klant_Test_Resultaat_Links <= 50] <- "3"
Dataset$Klant_Test_Resultaat_Links[Dataset$Klant_Test_Resultaat_Links > 50 & Dataset$Klant_Test_Resultaat_Links <= 65] <- "4"
Dataset$Klant_Test_Resultaat_Links[Dataset$Klant_Test_Resultaat_Links > 65 & Dataset$Klant_Test_Resultaat_Links <= 80] <- "5"
Dataset$Klant_Test_Resultaat_Links[Dataset$Klant_Test_Resultaat_Links > 80 & Dataset$Klant_Test_Resultaat_Links <= 95] <- "6"
Dataset$Klant_Test_Resultaat_Links[Dataset$Klant_Test_Resultaat_Links > 95] <- "7"

# transform the variable to a factor
Dataset$Klant_Test_Resultaat_Links <- as.factor(Dataset$Klant_Test_Resultaat_Links)

# Check hte summary statistics
summary(Dataset$Klant_Test_Resultaat_Links)
```

Yet, a problem is that somehow classes 1 up until 6 are correct, while certain values with a value between 100 and 200 are not assigned to class 7. When checking the summary statistics of my new variable I find the following:
[image: Summary overview]

The weird part is that some values are correctly assigned to class 7, while other values between 100 and 200 aren't. Anybody knows what's the issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to categorize numerical ranges in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66096190/how-to-categorize-numerical-ranges-in-r)

Comment: Please add data using `dput` not as images.

Comment: Thanks, the sapply() function seems to work!